# Are all vectors column vectors?

Tags: matrices, vectors

I am reading a ML book it says all vectors are column vectors.  Is this true in general in books (and especially in practice) that all vectors are implied to be column vectors.  Or is it just for that book.

I see a lot of $X^TX$ in books, which would make sense if we assume X is a column vector.

Comment: Well... I‘d say a vector is an element of a vector space.

Comment: But yeah, I would guess that it is an assumption in your book.

Comment: It is usual to write elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a column because it fits in well with matrix multiplication, etc.

Comment: It is the convention to write a vector as a column.  There might be some books that use a different convention, however.

Comment: I think of them as functions $x:\{1,...,n\} \to \mathbb{R}$ :-).

Comment: I think the author probably means, "All vectors in this book should be understood to be column vectors."

Comment: Probably a convention. Any vector space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$, but you cannot write vectors from an infinite dimensional vector space (say a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$) as a column vector.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors are most often considered to be column vectors because if $v$ is a vector and $A$ is a matrix we want to write $Av$ instead of $vA$. This is simply a convention, and I'm sure at least one book reverses it and assumes all vectors are row vectors. I don't have an example handy though.

Comment: At least some editions of Herstein’s algebra text used right application of homomorphisms, so I suppose that any vectors there would have been the row kind.

Comment: James and Liebeck's book on group representations uses right applications as well and vectors would then be column vectors.